# Use two classes have the same XML type name

Tags: java, jaxb

I have this XML:

```
<account-holder>
        <first-name>John</first-name>
        <last-name>Doe</last-name>
        <address>
            <street1>123 anystreet</street1>
        </address>
    </account-holder>
    <shipping>
        <first-name>Manon</first-name>
        <last-name>Mertens</last-name>
        <address>
            <street1>Rue de la Loi 1</street1>
        </address>
        <shipping-method>home_delivery</shipping-method>
    </shipping>
```

As you can see I have in 2 places tag `address`. This is the JAXB which I use:

***Main Class:***

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "payment")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AuthorizeRequest { 

    @XmlElement(name = "account-holder")
    public AccountHolder accountHolder;

    @XmlElement(name = "shipping")
    public Shipping shipping;
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AccountHolder {
    ....
    @XmlElement(name = "address")
    private Address address;
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Shipping { 
    ....        
    @XmlElement(name = "address")
    private Address address;
}
```

***Address:***

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Address {

    @XmlElement(name = "street1")
    private String street1;

    @XmlElement(name = "street2")
    private String street2;
}
```

But I get exception:

```
Two classes have the same XML type name "{http://www.elastic-payments.com/schema/payment}address". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Do you use a different `Address` class in `AccountHolder` than in `Shipping`?

Comment: No, it's the same Java Class (in order to reduce the code duplication)

Comment: Can you paste the complete jaxb error message? Usually there is a list of locations where the error happens.

Comment: Unable to reproduce, though I would suggest you remove the `@XmlRootElement` from any class that will not be a root element, and only `AuthorizeRequest` is a root element.

Comment: Here is the full error: https://pastebin.com/k5EbtVbA

Comment: I tried with removed @XmlRootElement but the error is still present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the more detailed error message describes, you have (at least) two `Address` classes

`org.datalis.gateway.wirecard.models.authorize.request.Address`
`org.datalis.gateway.wirecard.models.authorize.response.Address`

There are several options

- add `@XmlType` annotations to them, maybe you can have a namespace for request and one for response
- Rename the classes to make them unique
- Separate the request/response context to make the class unique in that context